# Has anyone created an FTP adapter for the Windows Azure Service Bus Brokered Messaging service?

Tags: c#, ftp, azure, sftp, servicebus

Let us say that I have an FTP server getting XML files sent each day, and that I want to post theese to the Windows Azure Service Bus Brokered Messaging service.

Has anyone created a tool (and is willing to share) that will monitor a directoy and post these to the service bus?

Alternative, has anyone implemented an FTP server that will accept files and then post to the service bus?

Alternative, implementet FTP server in Azure that transforms messages to the service bus?

Comment: Sounds like you need to look at the `FileSystemWatcher` class; that, in combination with a simple Windows service running on the FTP host, should do what you need.

Comment: I have used that before. The implementation would be easy, but I was hoping someone already had made the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of. I use the [Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb736753) instead. Take a look at the [File Sync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb887623) [Provider](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/query/ff872391).

In my case, I went ahead and created a custom FTP sync provider to handle some aspects of the sync process that were specific to the application.  When the sync session finishes, I post BrokeredMessages to a ServiceBus queue, where worker instances process those messages (mostly Uri's to the location of the files now in Blob Storage).

Good luck!

Comment: Good idea. I will investigate this as an alternativ to http://ftp2azure.codeplex.com/

Comment: I would like to, but that decision is up to the client that I wrote it for. You I have heard that you can use the out-of-box file sync provider by mounting the FTP site as folder. I haven't tried it myself, however.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this solution as well now: http://ftp2azure.codeplex.com/